# OpenRTSP Qt integration for video rendering

Tags: qt, phonon, live555

I was trying to use Qt for playing live video for which Qt provides a phonon class. However, the limitation with this is that it is not capable of decoding RTSP packets on windows (since phonon uses Directshow on windows platform).

In order to make it capable of doing this, I am planning to now integrate openRTSP with Qt. Within openRTSP where can I find a pointer / handle to the video buffer or frame buffer so that I can pass on this to my Qt widget for display.

Has anyone attempted this before?
Any pointers on the correct approach for doing this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GStreamer and GStreamer Qt bindings. They provide VideoWidget etc so it should provide you enough code examples how you should do this: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html